# How to get all class of an element in jQuery using class selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to find all classes of every div but it is not working.
It works fine only using id selector but not in class selector.
I have tried in many ways but not success. So please anyone can solve this.
Any idea about how I can do this?
This is only demo code

```js
get_classes();

function get_classes() {
  $('.div1 .section').each(function() {
    var classList = $(this).attr("class");
    var classArr = classList.split(" ");
    if (classArr == 'like') {
      console.log(classArr)
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="section outer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, veniam?</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="section outer like">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, veniam?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're really after. A class is never equal to a string, so that's a problem. There are also no elements with the class `like` in your HTML, so the code will never find anything, so that's another issue. Finally, `$('.div1 .section.like').each(function () { console.log(this.attr('class').split(' ')); })` will perform the same thing as the code shown. If you actually want to get a list of classes for every element for some reason, there are ways of doing it, but it seems like an XY Problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From your question it is somewhat unclear what you intend so here are some examples (somewhat verbose for clarity)

```js
function getAllUniqueClasses() {
  let foundClasses = [];
  $('.div1')
    .find('.section')
    .each(function() {
      let myClass = this.classList;
      foundClasses = [...new Set([...foundClasses, ...myClass])];
    });
  return foundClasses;
}

function getAllClasses() {
  let allClasses = [];
  $('.div1')
    .find('.section')
    .each(function() {
      let myClass = this.classList;
      allClasses = [...allClasses, ...myClass];
    });
  return allClasses;
}

function hasClass(findMe) {
  let hasOne =
    $('.div1')
    .find('.section')
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).hasClass(findMe);
    });
  return !!hasOne.length;
}

console.log("Unique:", getAllUniqueClasses());
console.log("All:", getAllClasses());
let me = 'like';
console.log("found:", hasClass(me));

//Get all elements with a class:
let $have = $('.div1')
  .find('.section')
  .filter('.like');
//how many we found
console.log($have.length);
//show all in each we found:
$have.each(function() {
  console.log('Here:', [...this.classList])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="section outer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, veniam?</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="section outer like">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, veniam?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So here I see 2 problems.

The first one, is your top selector. Using your provided html you have to iterate over parent divs first and inside find the corresponding div. Smth like:

```
function get_classes() {
  $('.div1').each(function() {
  var $section = $(this).find('.section');
  
    $section.each(function() {
```

The second problem is that you tries to check if array is equal to string ( String.split() returns array as per [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)).

Please find below working example:

```js
function get_classes() {
  $('.div1').each(function() {
    var $section = $(this).find('.section');

    $section.each(function() {
      var classList = $(this).attr("class");
      var classArr = classList.split(" ");
      if (classArr.indexOf('like') !== -1) {
        console.log(classArr)
      }
    });

  });
}

get_classes();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="section outer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, veniam?</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="section outer like">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, veniam?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```